# use variational_recurrent in tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper

Tags: tensorflow

In the api of [tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/DropoutWrapper), I am trying to set `variational_recurrent=True`, in which case, input_size is mandatory. As explained, `input_size` is `TensorShape` objects containing the **depth(s)** of the input tensors.

**depth(s)** is confusing, what is it please? Is it just the shape of the tensor as we can get by `tf.shape()`? Or the number of channels for the special case of images? But my input tensor is not an image.

And I don't understand why `dtype` is demanded when `variational_recurrent=True`.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first question: Your input to the RNN cell will be some multidimensional tensor of shape `[batch_size, max_time, ...]`. Depth refers to the '...' dimensions. For example, when your input has shape `(20, 35, 100)` the depth is 100. In this case, `input_size` in the Dropout wrapper would be 100.

Answer (score 1):

Inpput_size for tf.TensorShape([200, None, 300]) is just 300

Play with this example.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see TF issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5
keep_prob = 0.5
learning_rate = 0.001


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
X_seqs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(X, perm=[1, 0, 2]))

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons)
basic_cell_drop = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
    basic_cell,
    input_keep_prob=keep_prob,
    variational_recurrent=True,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    input_size=n_inputs)

output_seqs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
    basic_cell_drop,
    X_seqs,
    dtype=tf.float32)
outputs = tf.transpose(tf.stack(output_seqs), perm=[1, 0, 2])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

X_batch = np.array([
        # t = 0      t = 1 
        [[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]], # instance 1
        [[3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0]], # instance 2
        [[6, 7, 8], [6, 5, 4]], # instance 3
        [[9, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1]], # instance 4
    ])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    outputs_val = outputs.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch})


print(outputs_val)
```

See this for more details: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7927